# VB.Net , Can't click button, No ID or Name

Tags: html, vb.net

I am trying to get a balance checker for Adnooka, but I can't even get past the login.
Here's the HTML:

```
        </div>
          <div class="control-group row-fluid">
          <label class="row-fluid " for="inputPassword">Password <div class="pull-right"><a class="muted"><small><a href='http://adnooka.com/recover'>Forgot your password ?</a></small></a></div></label>
          <div class="controls row-fluid input-append">
            <input type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password"  name="password" class="row-fluid" value=""> <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-lock"></i></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group row-fluid fluid">
          <div class="controls span6">
          </div>
          <div class="controls span5 offset1" style=''>
            <button type='submit' class="btn btn-default" style='float:right'>Login<i class="gicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
```

But the Button has no ID or Name, how can I click it?
How how can I return the value of a balance?

Here's what I've got so far:

```
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("email").SetAttribute("value", textbox1.Text)
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("password").SetAttribute("value", pass.Text)
    Dim allelements As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.All

    For Each webpageelement As HtmlElement In allelements

        If webpageelement.GetAttribute("type") = "submit" Then

            webpageelement.InvokeMember("click")

        End If

    Next

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://adnooka.com/login")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can invoke a `submit` on the form itself, you don't have to find a button to click.

This should work, if you have only one form on the page. If not, adjust the [0] to whatever is needed:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.Forms[0].InvokeMember("submit")
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.forms.aspx for more details.

Comment: Thank you alot for the answer, but what you mean by GetElementByType("form").

Comment: Thanks alot for introducing me to this feature. I found a way to make it work, your method doesn't work